# Trying to append a img to different parts of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

This is my HTML that creates a board, each cell calls my JavaScript Function on click creates an Image.  Currently the image is created in the body and is visible under the table. I would like it so that when you click on a cell the Image is created in that Cell.

```html
 <pre><div id="board">
   <table>
   <th colspan="3">Infinite Tic-Tac-Toe!</th>
     <tr id="row1">
       <td class="square" onclick="add_X();">
       </td>
       <td class="square v" onclick="add_X();">
       </td>
       <td class="square" onclick="add_X();"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
       <td class="square h" onclick="add_X();"></td>
       <td class="square v h" onclick="add_X();"></td>
       <td class="square h" onclick="add_X();"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row3">
       <td class="square" onclick="add_X();"></td>
       <td class="square v" onclick="add_X();"></td>
       <td class="square" onclick="add_X();"></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
      </div></code>
```

Here is my JavaScript with the function that is currently creating the images in the body and not the table.

```js
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;

  // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
  this.appendChild(img); 
};

function add_X(){
  var src = "http://bookriotcom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/x.png";
  show_image('http://bookriotcom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/x.png', 60, 60, "X")
};

function add_O(){
  var src = "http://store.hamiltonmarine.com/prodimg/BER-O.JPG";
  show_image('http://store.hamiltonmarine.com/prodimg/BER-O.JPG', 50, 50, "x")
}
```

I'm trying to create my own tic Tac Toe game with out copying someone else and am currently struggling with getting the X to go inside the clicked square. 
You can check out what I have managed so far here.
http://terribilis.github.io/Infinite-Tic-Tac-Toe/

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. We aren't going to write your code for you. If you'd like our help - please have a go and write something yourself (even if it doesn't work) and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: Wow you guys are quick. I was trying to edit it. I'm only asking if there is some way to append an element to a changing parent. At least I think thats how you would say it. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: I've tried changing the code to this.appendChild(img) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function show_image(sender, src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;


  //document.body.appendChild(img); //DO NOT DO THIS.

  //REPLACE WITH BELLOW CODE

   $(sender).append(img);

};

function add_X(){
  var src = "http://bookriotcom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/x.png";
  show_image($(this),'http://bookriotcom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/x.png', 60, 60, "X")
};

function add_O(){
  var src = "http://store.hamiltonmarine.com/prodimg/BER-O.JPG";
  show_image($(this),'http://store.hamiltonmarine.com/prodimg/BER-O.JPG', 50, 50, "x")
}
```

please note that i added extra parameter, to get the sender, so each time function add_x or add_o is being called, you have to pass it's sender, and use it in show_image function to know which row u want ur img to be appended.

Comment: I'm new to coding so forgive me for not understanding. So would this code work so that you click on the cell and then the image is created in the cell with no other input, or does there need to be something that will cover this keyword?

Comment: Yes the Code didn't work. the Image is not visible at all now. Does your code create a new <td> Because that is not my goal. I want the image to go into the prexisting Cells.

Comment: i give u 2 options, the first one is to append in new TD, but the second one is to append in the same cell. if that what u want, i have edited my code, it should work, if it does not, then can u tell me what error it show in console?

Comment: I don't know where the console is on github. Is it possible the image is being created but is underneath the table and changing the z-index would fix it?

Comment: just use firebug in firefox, or u can use chrome console.. i don't know what the problem if u don't show me what error it show. + if u sure z-index is the problem, why don't u just inspect ur page element, and check if there an image element is created there.

Comment: OKay I checked my page element and nothing is being created. The console doesn't show any errors. The image is just not being created anymore.